# Ubuntu NFS mount bind failing

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, bind, bind-mount

This should be a rather simple question, but all my googlefu has failed me so far. I have an nfs server with a share mounted to my local machine in dir /share/ `(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)` from there I want to mount bind a folder within /share/userdata to my user user directory /home/user/nfs I am able to mount /share/ just fine, however when running this command `sudo mount --bind /share/userdata /home/user/nfs` I am returned the error "mount: /home/user/nfs: bind /share/userdata failed." No further details are given and I can't make heads or tails of this error. Does anyone have any clue what is going on or if this is even possible?

Comment: Are the src/dest dirs available? Also, bind mounts are only supported within the same file system. Ensure that both /share/userdata and /home/user/nfs are on the same file system.